# How can I use consecutive conditional clause in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements, case-when

I was trying to work with CASE WHEN in Postgresql in order to evaluate something and then do another thing. However, I need not only to check two things but they must be checked in consecutive order.

Example, let's say I have 3 columns: col1, col2 and col3.
I want to check first if col1 is greater than 0. After checking this I want to check if col2 is greater than 0. If that's the case, I will create another column which will be the sum of all of them. However, I can't do this:

```
select case when col1>0 and col2>0 then col1+col2+col3 end as...
```

I need to do something like this:

```
select case when col1>0 then (case when col2>0 then col1+col2+col3) else NULL end as...
```

But that doesn't work. So, what can I do?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Why can't you use the first version?  It looks correct to me.

Comment: Actually your first query with AND does exactly what you want. If the condition col1>0 is false then processing the statement terminates; the second condition would NOT even processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You can do:

```
select 
  case when col1 > 0 then case when col2 > 0 then col1 + col2 + col3 end
       else NULL end as my_column1
```

You had missed the inner `end`.

By the way, a `CASE` expression evaluates to `NULL` when no `when` clause is matched. Therefore, `else NULL` is redundant.